# Waze API for Android

Tags: android, traffic-measurement

I want to develop an android application which retrieving data from the Waze Live Map (to supply some input - like from where to where and get the time it would take to drive that route regard to the traffic jams and all other staff..)
On Waze website i only found instructions to build the same application but not to use it with API.

Is there an API to android so I could do my thing?

thanks,
Bush

Comment: just sent email to the waze company, waiting for an answer..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After contacting with Waze company by mails I have the answer: No.
They didn't released API for their app and so we cannot build app relying on it...

well, we'll wait for google navigator :)

Comment: can we pass srcLatlng and destLatlng in intent of Waze app ?
can we use like that ?

Answer (score 4):

open-source project that wrapper waze functionality

its written in java. can be used as a service or as a runnable server.

https://github.com/Nimrod007/waze-api

link to docs:

http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/Nimrod007/waze-api/blob/master/docs.html

Comment: So am I allowed to use this unofficial API commercially? Waze doesn't restrict this?

Comment: https://www.waze.com/robots.txt allows this, regarding if waze will restrict this after you use this in a large scale .. its up to them

Comment: Does this still work?
Can we use this in a commercial project?
Also, is there any official API documentation on waze that we can use for routes/directions and distance calculations? @Nimrod007